# How to use AWS lambda and S3 together to fetch results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sitespeedio

I am using sitespeed.io to measure performance of some of my static URL's and uploading the results into AWS S3 bucket.
Inside AWS S3 bucket it is structured exactly how sitespeed outputs the data. I have attached an image for it and when you go inside that folder what you see is `index.html` which shows all the details of the pages configured.

Now I have a page which has a calendar and when you select any date, it should show all the folders of that date. When you click on that folder it should open the `sitespeed.io` summary page. I've attached that as well. Unfortunately I can't share anything else from the code.

What i want to know is it possible to trigger a `lambda` function using a rest API which will fetch the result from `S3` or `dynamoDB` and display on the front end for user to view?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly possible. Was there something specific that you wanted to understand?

Comment: @jarmod yes I don't know how and where to start. What i know is we need a lambda function which will be invoked everytime the rest API gets called and will fetch the results from S3. If you can point me to a starting point as in how do i write the function that would be helpful

Comment: You could start [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html), or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html) .